# Need explanation about row selecting in Java

Tags: java

```
    public void moveRowBy(int b){
        int[] rows = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
        int des = rows[0] + b;

        if(des<0 || des >= tableRows){
            return;
        }

        jTable1.setRowSelectionInterval(rows[0] + b, rows[0] + b);
        System.out.println(rows.length);
    }
```

This is my homework to select rows in table
can someone explain what the rows[0] does ? thankss

Comment: It gets the first element of the array `rows`.

Comment: Read about Arrays in Java

Comment: Each element of the array rows is the index of a table row that is currently selected.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are a fixed-size collection of elements of a specific data type. Elements of an array are accessed using square brackets enclosing the index to access; arrays are zero-indexed, which means the first element is at index 0 and the last element is at index `array.length - 1`.

In your example, `rows[0]` simply accesses the first element of the `int` array `rows`.

See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for a more thorough tutorial on Java Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
rows[0]
```

It access to the first element of the integer array `rows`. Similarly if you want to access to 2nd element then just write `rows[1]`

And If you want to iterate over the array `rows` and to see all the elements just do like below:

```
 for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
    System.out.println((i+1)+" element => "+rows[i]);
 }
```